# TypeError: container.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript

Знаю, что ошибка глупая, но не могу выловить ее уже минут 10-15

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.onclick = function() {
    alert(i);
  }
  //div.innerHTML = 'sime';
  container.appendChild(div); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

Comment: вы получаете коллекцию элементов, а не конкретный элемент. более того, `.appendChild` добавит только последний созданный в цикле `div`.

Comment: @ya.ymer, поправил пример, случайно забыл поменять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По классу вы получаете не элемент, а массив элементов. Поэтому их надо либо перебрать, либо указать индекс массива.

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'bla-bla';
  div.onclick = function() {
    alert(i);
  }
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.bla-bla {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName вернет объект со списком элементов, Вам нужно обратиться к первому из них.
Либо можно использовать document.querySelector(".container"); - вернет первый элемент либо null.

```js
var clickHandler = function(e) { 
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
};
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i;
  div.onclick = clickHandler;
  container[0].appendChild(div); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```